# what is wrong with this ServiceStack Put method

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack, protobuf-net

Client connects, sends Put:

```
var client = new JsvServiceClient(ConfigGlobal.Host);
client.Put(new PiecParametrySzczegoloweRequest { Initialize = true, Config = _config });
```

Server receives call and don't see `Initialize` variable value is set to `true`:

```
internal class PiecParametrySzczegoloweService : Service
{
    public PiecParametrySzczegoloweResponse Put(PiecParametrySzczegoloweRequest request)
    {
        if (request.Initialize)
        {
            ImageFile.Initialize(request.Config);

            request.Initialize = false;

            return new PiecParametrySzczegoloweResponse { Initialized = true };
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Request looks like:

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/PiecParametrySzczegolowe")]
public class PiecParametrySzczegoloweRequest : IReturn<PiecParametrySzczegoloweResponse>
{
    public bool Initialize { get; set; }

    public PiecParametrySzczegoloweLegend Config { get; set; }

    public int Percent { get; set; }
}
```

### Edit:

It was lack of attribute, thanks! And (problems resolved in meantime)...

If you need `/requestlogs` and you don't have auth use:

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature() { RequiredRoles = new string[0] });
```

If you need serialize binary data (Bitmap) use protobuf-net (`var client = new ProtoBufServiceClient(ConfigGlobal.Host);`) and do something like this [Serialize a Bitmap in C#/.NET to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907077/serialize-a-bitmap-in-c-net-to-xml)

If you don't want (need) to annotate every field member (read warnings) [Protobuf-net serialization without annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308196/protobuf-net-serialization-without-annotation)

Comment: What version of ServiceStack are you using? I recreated your service and cannot reproduce the error. The `Initialize` value was set to `true` for me. When you breakpoint on the line `if(request.Initialize)` are the other request parameters set correctly? Do you use a proxy? Try adding the requestlog plugin `Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature());` then check `/requestlogs`.

Comment: I'm using ServiceStack.3.9.68 without proxy. I'll try requestlog

Comment: 3.9.71 is the latest BSD version. But your problem may become clear once you see the requests.

Comment: @Scott Updated to latest, `/requestlogs` shows Connection Keep-Alive
 Content- Length 2
 Content- Type application/jsv
 Accept
application/jsv
 Accept- Encoding
gzip
 Expect
100-continue
 Host
localhost:1337, other columns (except Items and duration) are empty.

Comment: It occurs to me remove `[DataContract]` attribute, as you are not defining `[DataMember]`s so it's not serializing the object properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `[DataContract]` attribute because this attribute tells the serializer that **you will specify the fields to include for serialization** using the `[DataMember]` attribute, but you haven't done so.

Or alternatively mark your properties with `[DataMember]`.

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/PiecParametrySzczegolowe")]
public class PiecParametrySzczegoloweRequest : IReturn<PiecParametrySzczegoloweResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Initialize { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public PiecParametrySzczegoloweLegend Config { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Percent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, using DataContract's makes fields opt-in. Here are some other ways to [ignore fields in ServiceStack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14859968/85785).