# Protobuf and Entity Framework DataBase Model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, protobuf-net

I have the EF databaseModel.
I serialize my class thet contains field with EF DB Table Type.
I try to deserealize and i have the field with null fields.

```
class Myclass
{
    public EFTable table {get;set;}
}
```

EFTable

- string str;
- int num;

[global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]      [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]

After deserialization
EFTable
- string str=null
- int num=0

why? how fix it without creating temp classes?

```
public static byte[] Serialize(BaseInspection inspection)
{
    using (var file = File.Create(path.ToString()))
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(file, inspection);
    }
    return File.ReadAllBytes(path.ToString());
}

static BaseInspection Desirialize(byte[] path)
{

    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(path))
        return Serializer.Deserialize<BaseInspection>(stream);           
}
```

Comment: Post your EFTable. Do have any Proto attributes on properties of EFTable?

Comment: All are standart when create the EF DataBase Model\Scheme

Comment: ProtoBuf has two ways to specify order of fields. First one is to specify Attributes on each property. Second one - is to create this `RuntimeTypeModel` in runtime and fill it with reflection

Comment: Ok, I know that I do not set attributes to EF model, it is too long and I generete my db model many times, it means that I sould rewrite attributes again many time. How I can do it fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't specify attributes under your model, you can go with second approach to fill `RuntimeTypeModel` at application start. Here is a sample given my Marc Gravell - [Protobuf-net serialization without annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308196/protobuf-net-serialization-without-annotation)

Code sample for your `EFTable`:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(EFTable), false).Add("str", "num",);
```

Or you can fill it with reflection based on your EFTable properties, and then it should serialize correctly.

But beware, as Protobuf is critical to properties order. And if you fill this `RuntimeTypeModel` object dynamically by reflection, and then you will add new property, then data that was serialized with previous version, won`t work in new version, as properties order will be changed.

**UPDATE1**

As I mentioned you can also use reflection to populate fields dynamically. Here is a sample of such method:

```
public static void Generate(IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
    var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        var metaType = model.Add(type, false);

        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            metaType.Add(counter++, propertyInfo.Name);
        }

    }
}
```

And usage sample:

```
Generate(new List<Type>() { // list of objects that should be registered with ProtoBuf-Net
    typeof(ASPStateTempSession),  
    typeof(ASPStateTempApplication) 
});
```

But as i previously said, if you add new property in new version of your application, then old saved cached data won't work, as order of properties will be changed.

Comment: think it will be "ppc", I have 27 tables >.< thank you, will try

Comment: sorry for long answer. I've added a sample how to fill them dynamically

Comment: thank you, I used my own code to dynamically fill RuntimeTypeModel.Default =) But now I selected BinaryBufferization because I need save delegates too... I know that this is not good... but now I can't change anything in programm...

Answer (score 1):

If the classes are being generated, it is very likely they are being generated as `partial` classes. In which case, you can add the attributes separately in a separate code file:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoPartialMember(1, "table")]
    partial class Myclass {}
}
```

This will be merged at compile-time, and protobuf-net knows to look for the `ProtoPartialMember` alternative form.

Comment: Hi Marc, just curios, will it work with `MetadataTypeAttribute` attribute that can be used with EntityFramework to specify attributes for domain object in separate partial class? I'm talking about this one - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).aspx . If I specify Proto attributes in  MetaData class, will ProtoBuf use it?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov not at the current time, but it is something worth considering

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the answer. I'm not sure that it will be very useful, but it can be.