# Using ProtoBuf-Net for two different sets of serialization

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am using ProtoBuf-Net to send decorated objects over TCP - and it works like a charm.

But I want to serialize the same objects also into a file, with a different decoration. That means, I want to have other properties saved here.

I don't think manipulating attributes is possible at runtime, so what other options do I have?

Thanks in advance!

(I'm very sorry if this was asked before, but I was unable to find anything with the search term 'different')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation:

> Alternative to attributes
>   In v2, everything that can be done with attributes can also be configured at runtime via >RuntimeTypeModel. The Serializer.* methods are basically just shortcuts to >RuntimeTypeModel.Default., so to manipulate the behavior of Serializer., you must >configure RuntimeTypeModel.Default.

or this question:
[Protobuf-net serialization without annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308196/protobuf-net-serialization-without-annotation)

Basically, instead of annotations, you can configure everything yourself through the RuntimeTypeModel

Comment: And more specifically: a *second* model instance (`TypeModel.Create()`). Good answer.

Comment: Thank you and you @MarcGravell for confirming. Could I let the 1st set still use the annotations and just the 2nd programmatically?

Comment: @copa017 yes; as long as you pass `false` as the auto-configure parameter when adding types to the 2nd model, it ignores everything