# protobuf-net property indexers

Tags: servicestack, protobuf-net

In protobuf-net,
Is there a plan to  add support for attribute-less POCOs, to avoid the property indexes (ProtoContact) ?

I have not  problem   to add indexes for each property on DTO.

I create the DTOs  automatically with my  utility and there is  a  configuration flag for protobuf members.

The problem is that using RESTful services with ServiceStack,

I share to customers (who work in .Net)   2 assemblies,

1. the model without any dependencies, nor ServiceStack (not IReturn), nor  protobuf-net.
2. The client.requests, which is a thin  wrapper  to actual service calls, with some validation,

   error handling, etc. Essentially are simplified calls for every service.

   This  assembly has dependencies on ServiceStack client and Protobuf-net.

But the model  is dependency-free, because customers can use it,  directly in their business layer.

In this case, I have problem with protobuf-net,  not with ServiceStack as IReturn is not mandatory.

Is there any solution about that, to avoid add protobuf indexers ?

**Update:**  thanks to **Mark Gravell**, his answer here and in [previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8179429)

the solution is the alternative inline attributes,

[XmlType]/[XmlElement(Order=key)]  using only System.Xml,

or [DataContract]/[DataMember(Order=key)] using System.Runtime.Serialization.

So the model is dependency free, without  references to protobuf-net.

I should have read better  about.

```
         [XmlType("Person")]
        public class Person
        {
          [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
          public string Name { get; set; }

          [XmlElement( Order = 2)]
          public string Address { get; set; }
       }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options present themselves:

- if the generated code is a `partial` class, you can create a **second** partial class file for the same type, and add the attributes *there* - this is then part of the same type; in particular, note that `[ProtoPartialMember(...)]` can be added to a *type* (multiple times), but describes a *member*; or if you want less maintenance, `[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields=ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]` can be used to let the model take control of the rules (but please read the intellisense remarks on `ImplicitFields` before doing this)
- you can configure the type at runtime, using whatever rules you want, via `RuntimeTypeModel`:

  ```
  var metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(yourType, false);
  // TODO: some reflection that decides what members you want to serialize
  // and as what keys
  foreach(...)
      metaType.Add(member, key);
  ```

Comment: I would prefer first option, as I can generate the code.  Question: the second option has reflection  overhead ?

Comment: @stefan2410 only when you configure the model, which you would only do once

Comment: Also, more important question about the partial class.  Do you mean that in client side,  I will give both,  the dependency free model assembly for customer integration and the   model with attributes together with  the client.requests assembly  for the actual service calls ?     Or attributes don't required in client side.

Comment: @stefan2410 I don't think I mean either of those things; what I am saying is that if, by whatever mechanism, you have some generated `partial` classes, then *one option* is to add the attributes by using `partial class` in a second file. Now, as per the second bullet above, indeed it is true that attributes are not required - they are simply more convenient that configuring the model via code

Comment: I was not clear before. I have understood the 2 options. The second option is not viable for me, because the DTOs are predefined with customers ( CRUD or query results). To serialize them in code, it seems error-prone.  What I asked above is that in first option, (maybe naive question)  the client side code needs the keys  to deserialize the buffer? I think yes .   In this case, with the partial class, I can give to customer a dependency free model for further integration in its system, and a model assembly with proto-keys for the actual client request. Is it correct?

Comment: @stefan2410 if all the client gets is C# classes, then that won't work well - it needs more information; if they get a dll, there may be options. What do they get?

Comment: they get 2 dll's. First with model only  (C# classes) the second with  client requests (wrappers of service calls). I can include in the second dll, the partial class with attributes.  Also, according to your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8179429/2103764) can I use for attributes the [XmlType]/[XmlElement(Order=key)], as you write, so avoid dependency in protobuf ?

Comment: @stefan2410 yes, you can use alternative attributes; either the XmlSerializer ones (as cited) or the WCF/DataContractSerializer ones

Comment: yes, I should have read  better, about the  alternative attributes.  In this case, I have a dependency free model. thank you.